# Issue with capt-of package

Tags: hyperref, captions, warnings

I'm using the capt-of package to create a caption for my figures:

```
\newcommand\figureFrame[4]{%
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
        \captionof{figure}{#3}\label{#4}
    \end{center}
}
```

Now I get the following error whenever a cite is in my caption text:

```
pdflatex> Package caption Warning: The option `hypcap=true' will be ignored for this
pdflatex> (caption)                particular \caption on input line 112.
```

I looked at the [documentation](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/capt-of/capt-of.pdf), but found nothing for "hypcap". How can I fix this or do I have to fix this?

(There's now minimum working example because I think the answer is only a hint to the correct place in documentation :-))

Comment: BTW: Loading the `capt-of` package has no effect when the `caption` package is loaded, too. But I must confess that I don't know if I have documented this, will take a look now...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This warning comes from the `caption` package, not `capt-of`. See section 6.5 of the [`caption` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) for details of `hypcap`.

Comment: Ok, this sounds like my problem :-) But what to do now? I need the hyperref package to use it for chapter links etc. and I want refs to a figure to be placed at the beginning of the figure and not the caption. Replace the hyperref package?

Comment: Try putting `\captionsetup{type=figure}` immediately before the `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: looks like section 7.6 of the documentation now

Answer (score 22):

Quoting from pp. 37--38 of the documentation of the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) (!) package:

> `\captionof{htypei}{. . . }` vs.
>   `\captionsetup{type=htypei}+\caption{. . .}`
>
> Without `hyperref` loaded, both will give you identical results. But
>   with `hyperref` loaded, and with `hypcap=true` requested, the
>   hyperlink anchor will be placed different. For example:
>
> ```
> \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
> . . .
> \captionof{figure}{A figure}
> \end{minipage}
> ```
>
> will place the hyperlink anchor at the caption. (And if `hypcap=true`
>   is set, you will get a warning about this.)