# Package caption warning: The option `hypcap=true' will be ignored for this particular \caption

Tags: captions, warnings

I am getting a warning regarding the `\caption` package when I try to put the caption to a Table.

This is my code:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Course} & \textbf{Completion Rate}& \textbf{Interaction Rate}\\
    \hline \hline
    ISec 2014 & 45.81\% & 80.09\%\\
    \hline
    ISec 2016 & 41.44\% & 54.28\%\\
    \hline
    ISec 2018 & 72.37\% & 88.33\%\\
    \hline
    ISec 2020 & 39.88\% & 63.21\%\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{Estimates of courses.}
    \label{tab:course-summary}
\end{center}
```

The warning message on console:

```
Package caption Warning: The option `hypcap=true' will be ignored for this particular \caption on input line 142. See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

I have come from this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32344/issue-with-capt-of-package) but could not get this warning solved.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to disable the warning, you can configure caption to not use the hypcap package for tables which will change the default behavior of the hyperlink anchor placement from the beginning of the containing float to where the caption is.

```
\captionsetup[table]{hypcap=false}
```

I believe the source of the issue is there is no containing float environment to create an anchor to.